# how to make search bar in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, search, searchbar

I want to make a search bar in unity which will act like a google search bar. I want to make this for search images in unity hierarchy and it also show recommendations when i start searching for an image with its name. please help me thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do it in editor or at runtime? 
I'll asume you want to do it at runtime.

```
Image[] images=FindObjectsOfType<Image>();// all Image components in your scene
Image[] images= GetComponentsInChildren<HingeJoint>();//i suggest you to call this one on the parent of all images, so you will retrive only images in child gameObjects.
```

assuming the gameObject name is your image name, this will sort your list by name:

```
List<Order> imagesSortedByName= images.OrderBy(o=>o.gameObject.name).ToList();
```

assuming the gameObject name is your image name, this will find all Images with "example" as gameObject.name's substring

```
List<Image> result= new List<Image>();
foreach(Image img in images)//simplified and understandable code
{
 if(img.gameObject.name.contains("example")
  {
     result.add(img);
  }
}
```

assuming you don't want your gameObject's name be your Image name:

Create your class:

```
class MyImage
{
  public string name;
  public Image image;
}

List<MyImage> images= FindObjectsOfType<Image>().toList();
then use the MyImage.name to identify your images
```